# Save log in separate directory during restart of Cassandra

Tags: logging, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am working with Datastax enterprise 4.5. I am looking for a setting that stores old system and console logs of cassandra in some history folder when the service is restarted. Is there a setting (where and how to use it) like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Log rotation config:

You can configure log rotation for system.log in log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.R.maxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.R.maxBackupIndex=50
```

And output.log in /etc/logrotate.d/cassandra

```
/var/log/cassandra/output.log {
  size 10M
  rotate 9
  missingok
  copytruncate
  compress
}
```

Log files will only grow to the specified size and get a generation number added to the end. I.E. system.log.1, system.log.2

#### Use the OpsC Backup service:

You can schedule the OpsCenter backup service to perform mv / backup for your logs using the [before or after scripts](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/online_help/opscBackupsCustomScripts_c.html?scroll=opscBackupsCustomScripts_c). Usually this is used for backing up sstables but there's no reason why it wouldn't work for logs too if you need.

#### Use Chrontab:

Alternatively, if you want to move / backup the old logs without OpsC, use [chron](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)